# EPPlus formula not running - no result

Tags: excel, sum, epplus

I am trying to calculate the sum of the column using this code and it is not displaying anything.

```
ws.Cells["C51"].Formula = "SUM(C3:C50)";
```

Am I missing something? Is there a place where it needs to be put? (such as after populating the cells)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe post more of your code.  You shouldnt need the equal sign and what you have looks good.  This works just fine even if you comment out the for loop (shows 0 in C51):

```
[TestMethod]
public void Sum_Formula_Test()
{
    var newFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\Temp\Temp.xlsx");
    if (newFile.Exists)
        newFile.Delete();

    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
    {
        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30650055/epplus-formula-not-running-no-result
        var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");

        for (var i = 3; i <= 50; i++)
            ws.Cells[String.Format("C{0}", i)].Value = i*10;

        ws.Cells["C51"].Formula = "SUM(C3:C50)";

        package.Save();
    }
}
```

Maybe you are overwriting the cell value in later in your logic.